# Django CMS bootstrap navbar always collapsed in IE8

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, django-templates, django-cms

Hello I am developing a django cms for my company but running into issues with the navbar in IE8.

using:

-Python 2.7.6

-Django (1, 7, 8, 'final', 0)

-django-cms 3.1.0

-boostrap 3.3.4

here is my template

```
{% load cms_tags staticfiles sekizai_tags menu_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>{% block title %}This is my new project home page{% endblock title %}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
    {% render_block "css" %}
  </head>
  <body style="padding-top:60px">
    {% cms_toolbar %}
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {% show_menu 0 1 100 100 "menu.html" %}
              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
        </div>
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script src="{% static 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
    {% render_block "js" %}
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue is the navbar is always collapsed regardless of the screen size

I have already had the navbar working in IE + Bootstrap and that template is like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'core:home' %}">
        {% load staticfiles %}
        <img alt='Bell logo' src="{% static 'core/images/bell_logo.png' %}">
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Liens</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Doc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wiki</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Project</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CAB</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DB</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</div>
```

I tried adapting my django cms template so it would look like the one I originally had, but no success. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where you're including [Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond), which is [required for media queries to work in IE8.](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#support-ie8-ie9)

Comment: How did respond.js fix your problem would it not be a .collapse conflicting with the same class in the django admin css ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to add respond.js to page, but i thought the cms and django would take care of that